# why this code in access Vb code gives me syntax error compiler error

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()

If Frame1 = 1 Then 'Code
   strRowsource = "select [Code],[Category],[product]" & "from giggly " & _
   " where[Code] Like '* "&Me.txtSearch.Text&" *'"`
End If
List1.RowSource = strRowsource
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting?

Comment: Also, you should probably use a different way to access your database... what you are doing is potentially dangerous. https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection

Answer (score 4):

Need a space in front of `from` and after `where`. Also need spaces around ampersands but not spaces around asterisks.

If intent is for listbox to be modified with each character typed in textbox, use Change event and Text property. Also set AutoExpand to No. Otherwise use AfterUpdate and then not use Text property, use Value. Since Value is default property don't have to specify.

Also, remove unnecessary concatenation.

```
   strRowsource = "SELECT [Code], [Category], [product] FROM giggly " & _
   "WHERE [Code] Like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*'"
```